# Why are MAMP virtual hosts working on my laptop but not my new iMac?

Tags: mamp, virtualhost, vhosts

I have two Macs (Macbook Air & iMac) and want to use Dropbox as the source for local website files and their corresponding databases.

I setup the databases [following these instructions](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Irq-uJA-aaA) ([text version here](http://simon-davies.name/mamp/syncing-mamp-with-dropbox)), moved the website files to Dropbox and synced the contents on both devices.

I've ensured that the correct files are in place as per virtual host instructions for MAMP, such as:

- added the domains to my hosts file at /etc/hosts
- uncommented the httpd.conf to include httpd-vhosts.conf
- added the ServerName and DocumentRoot like I'm supposed to (even changing out my user name in the path)

My laptop (the original computer where the sites were developed) works fine with the migrated databases and site files, but but when I start up MAMP and go to any dev virtual host url on my iMac, I'm met with a MAMP favicon and a blank screen with no content whatsoever.

How can I get my desktop to play nicely and access the databases correctly without error?

Thanks for any help addressing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

After manually deleting the MAMP folder from the Applications folder, I reinstalled a fresh copy of MAMP and ensured that enough time had passed for my Dropbox to sync, in addition to removing any conflicting file issues.

It seems that giving yourself a significant time delay between firing up MAMP on either machine helps in preventing database conflicts that must've been causing the issue.